# How do I create a meeting within a colleagues working hours in Outlook for web

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am using Outlook 365 and I use the web app version (so please ignore the desktop client).

I have set my [preferred working hours](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-work-hours-and-days-in-outlook-a27f261d-0681-415f-8ac1-388ab21e833f). When I look at my calendar, I can see where my day starts and ends based upon how the UI has been grayed out.

In this example, my day starts at 7:30 and finishes at 16:00! Even though I have 3 calendars selected, it only shows my working hours

[image]

The problem I have is, when I create an invite, I want to see if I'm choosing a time that suites my invitee's calendar. I know they have created their working hours in Outlook. The reason is, the main calendar view by work week is easier to eye ball for "empty spaces" than the thin view in the scheduling assistant

To make it clear, I'm not actually fussed about seeing everyone's start / end time - I want to know, based upon every invitee's start / end time, when will we all be in at the same time, and to see this by working week.

Is there a way to make this visible?

Comment: Please check if the below info is helpful to you. If you problem has been fixed, you could share your solutions or mark the best answer so that others with the same question will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the feature "**[Scheduling Assistant](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/schedule-with-outlook-on-the-web-68e9b7e8-33c0-4258-9eee-1b8d626dab5a)**"?

This assistant will tell you the working hours of the attendees when you book a meeting via OWA:

[image]

**Edit:**

For OWA, there doesn't seem to be any settings to show others' working hours in the main view. For Outlook desktop, you could add the scheduling assistant to the main tab so that you could view others' working hours: **[Where did Scheduling Assistant tab go when modifying meeting date?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/452527/where-did-scheduling-assistant-tab-go-when-modifyi.html)**

Comment: Sorry, no this is not helpful. My post already calls out my problem with the scheduling assistant.

Comment: It seems that I have misunderstood your requirement. Do you want to show others' working hours in your main calendar view?

Comment: Yes - exactly that! The only thing I care about is when everyone is in (as the scheduling assistant does) but if it shows by person as well, that also works

Comment: Based on my test and research, the working hours of attendees can only be viewed in Scheduling Assistant: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calendar-settings-in-outlook-web-app-84544ef2-d5cf-4696-bcb3-cc87719a3e07#:~:text=Set%20your%20working,suggested%20meeting%20times.

Comment: For OWA, there doesn't seem to be any settings to show others' working hours in the main view. For Outlook desktop, you could add the scheduling assistant to the main tab so that you could view others' working hours: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/452527/where-did-scheduling-assistant-tab-go-when-modifyi.html

Comment: Can you edit your post with your last comment - I think your comment about not possible in OWA but can be in the desktop is a great answer

Comment: I have updated my answer above. Thanks for your remind.